# Make ReactStrap/Bootstrap4 Cards In Separate Columns Same Height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I have an example at https://codesandbox.io/s/426277vml9. I am using separate columns because I want them to stack at low resolution.

Obviously, right now, height is a function of content, and so they are unequal. Is there any way (short of imposing a fixed height) to get them to automagically align to the same height?

```
  <Container fluid className="full-height bg-light">
      <Row className="h-100 justify-content-center full-height align-items-center bg-light">
        <Col xs="10" lg="3" className="p-0">
          <Card>
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle>LOGIN</CardTitle>
              <CardText>Sign in with your account.</CardText>
              <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                  <span className="input-group-text">
                    <i className="icon-user"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <Input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
              </InputGroup>
              <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                  <span className="input-group-text">
                    <i className="icon-lock"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <Input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
              </InputGroup>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                  <Button color="primary" className="px-4">Login</Button>
                </Col>
                <Col xs="12" lg="6" className="text-right">
                  <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col xs="10" lg="3" className="p-0">
          <Card color="primary">
            <CardBody className="text-white">
              <CardTitle>CREATE ACCOUNT</CardTitle>
              <CardText>If you want to create an account for your company to start using this product, click on the Create button. If your organization already has an account and you'd like to join it, click on the "Join" button.</CardText>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="12" md="6">
                  <Button color="success" className="px-4">Create</Button>
                </Col>
                <Col xs="12" md="6" className="text-right">
                  <Button color="success" className="px-4">Join</Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
```

Comment: Would be nice to see why the downvote via a comment...

Comment: Probably cause this question gets asked far too often on SO. Did you search for duplicates? On top of that, you are required to show your markup here within your question and not your site. Links go dead and this won't help anyone in the future. [mcve] I am shocked you don't know that already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840534/bootstrap-cards-with-100-height-and-margin-bottom

Comment: @Rob I cannot confirm the solution posted in the self-answer by the author in the linked post offers a solution. Not a working solution for **Bootstrap 4** anyway.

Comment: @WebDevBooster: I am using Reactstrap, which is Bootstrap4 as React components. I have edited the question title to better reflect this. My apologies.

Comment: @Rob: The MCV page doesn't stipulate the example must be inline. But, I get the point, I edited to have the relevant block of code also in the question.

Comment: @Rob, also the stated possible duplicate does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your markup slightly in order to achieve that. Below you will find the sample markup. Here is the breakdown:

- Separate the `.justify-content-center` class from the `.align-items-center` by applying the latter on the div with `.container-fluid` and also adding a `.d-flex` to this outer div.
- You can delete `.h-100 .full-height .bg-light` classes from the `.row` now.
- With this setup the divs with the `.col-10` will already be of same height, so the only thing left is to put `h-100` on the `.card`s, to make them fill up the vertical space.

```css
.full-height {
    min-height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex full-height align-items-center bg-light">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="p-0 col-10 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">LOGIN</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Sign in with your account.</p>
                        <div class="mb-3 input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input placeholder="Username" class="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-4 input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                                <button class="px-4 btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-right col-12 col-lg-6">
                                <button class="px-0 btn btn-link">Forgot password?</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="p-0 col-10 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card h-100 bg-primary">
                    <div class="text-white card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">CREATE ACCOUNT</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">If you want to create an account for your company to start using this product, click on the Create button. If your organization already has an account and you'd like to join it, click on the "Join" button.</p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <button class="px-4 btn btn-success">Create</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-right col-12 col-md-6">
                                <button class="px-4 btn btn-success">Join</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reactstrap's `CardDeck` for that.