# React - Bootstrap - Making columns all the same height

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Here is a fiddle showing my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/dbfev23h/

In essence, I have a React-Bootstrap `<Row>` tag and underneath it I am mapping over a list of books that I want rendered as "cards" to the screen. However, because of the size of the content, the heights of the "cards" are all over the place. How do I make the height of the cards to be uniformly the height of the max height of the card in that row?

One thing that may be an issue is that there is only one bootstrap `<Row>`, is that the issue?

In any case, I've tried the suggestions from stuff like: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/different-tricks-on-how-to-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height and [Bootstrap 4 Cards of same height in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451246/bootstrap-4-cards-of-same-height-in-columns) and [Make ReactStrap/Bootstrap4 Cards In Separate Columns Same Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567158/make-reactstrap-bootstrap4-cards-in-separate-columns-same-height) but nothing works.

Here is my actual code:

```
export class BooksComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Row>
                this.props.books.map((b, index) => (
                    <BookComponent
                        key={index}
                        title={b.title}
                        summary={b.summary}
                    />
                ))
            </Row>
        );
    }
}

export class BookComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Col md={4}>
                <div className="book-item">
                    <div className="book-title">{this.props.title}</div>
                    <div className="book-summary">{this.props.summary}</div>
                </div>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}
```

**SCSS**

```
.book-item {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;

    .book-title {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .book-summary {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px gray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your **`.col-md-4`**  as **flex** because then only you will be able to **stretch** the child elements.

```
.col-md-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.3333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Updated jsFiddle link>> https://jsfiddle.net/j8rhnsqd/1/

Comment: Do we need `align-self : stretch;` ?

Comment: No, not necessary. Updating the answer.

Comment: @devd Thank you for this. One last thing, how do I go about making the widths all the same width? I thought React-Bootstrap was supposed to take care of that for you but it doesn't appear so.

Comment: Bootstrap is indeed taking care of that but its the child of .col-md-4 that is creating issue.In book please use width:100%. It will do the job.

Comment: @devd This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!